What are the chidushim of The Lubavitcher Rebbe?
What are some of the most novel and unique chidushim of the Lubavitcher Rebbe? This is mainly regarding his Torah but can be his unique opinion on anything.
Primarily looking for specific examples of The Rebbe being completely mechadesh something in Torah learning.

His comments on Rashi on Chumash are gevaldig

@J.W.Tanner Can you please give (or link) one or two specific examples?

Here are something like 2000 sichot by the Lubavitcher Rebbe on the parasha, in english (and if you understand Yiddish, there are many more): https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/68159/jewish/Likkutei-Sichot-in-English.htm

Many examples are in the Gutnick edition of the Chumash

Every page of Likkutei Sichos has a chiddush. If you're interested in Rashi sichos, here's a nice collection of shiurim: https://www.chabad.org/multimedia/video_cdo/aid/3738610/jewish/Learning-Rashi-In-Depth.htm

See in particular this language from the Gutinck edition Chumash description: "The "Toras Menachem" commentary is culled from the extensive lectures and notes of the Lubavitcher Rebbe on classical and Hassidic interpretations, with special attention to his studies of Rashi's commentary" There are chidushim on nearly every page of the Gutnick edition Chumash

The maamar vishavti veshalom comes to mind. Some of this is built on previous chassidus but the way it is developed is unique at the same time. It's probably the longest edited maamar and is about 20 pages or so. You can find a shiur on this in yossi paltiels website inside chassidus. Look under the rebbe's mamaarim from 5738

Every such a or maamar he has ever said has at least one of his childishim, usually more

B"H
Obviously there are thousands, but one that comes to mind:
In Kimi tzeischa, 5712, he says that the verse "like the days you went out of Egypt", according to the simple meaning, is only referring to two days.
The question it starts with is how can it say "days" if the Exodus (going out of Egypt) was only in one day? It says explicitly "remember the day that you left Egypt", not the "days".
Deeper meanings that it references from other places are that the days refer to ALL of the days of the exile until moshiach comes, but this discourse gives a simple meaning.
On pesach they left the physical land of Egypt, but even after that, pharaoh sent agents to track where they are going etc, so they were still afraid of the Egyptians (and thus, Egypt itself).
But when they saw the Egyptians dead on the sea shore, they "left" even their fear of the Egyptians.
So the "days" you went out of Egypt are both the day of physically leaving the land, and the day they left the fear of Egypt.
The chiyuv duraissa is mainly to remember leaving the land of Egypt, but in birkos krias shema we also mention the splitting of the sea. It says in the discourse that if one forgets the 3rd paragraph of shema, which mentions leaving (the land of) Egypt, one needs to go back and say it, but if one is in doubt about if he said the brocho in shema that mentions krias yam suf, one does not go back, because even though remembering krias yam suf is a durayysa obligation, it does not prevent the mitzvah from being done, which is why the verse that commands us to remember the Exodus says, "remember the day you left Egypt".
It also mentions that in the hagadah we say that everyone who talks about the Exodus from Egypt a lot is praiseworthy, and right near that passage the hagadah goes on to talk extensively about krias yam suf, thus bringing further support that "going out of Egypt" includes the splitting of the sea
